# Changing cornerRadius using Core Animation

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-animation

I am trying to change the corner radius of a button (OpenNoteVisible.layer) in the following way:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction     functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.duration = 1.0;
[animation.layer setCornerRadius:140.0];
[OpenNoteVisible.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"cornerRadius"];
```

But this code gives an error at the line [animation.layer setCornerRadius:140.0];
I can't understand why. I have imported Quartz core framework.

Comment: You can set the corner radius to buttons. So use button objects

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're setting the corner radius on the layer property of the animation object; this animation object doesn't have a layer property.

You need to set the corner radius on the layer of the thing you're animating, in this case `OpenNoteVisible`. You also need to ensure the `toValue` of the animation object matches the value you're setting on the layer, otherwise you'll get odd animations.

Your code should now be:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction     functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:140.0f];
animation.duration = 1.0;
[OpenNoteVisible.layer setCornerRadius:140.0];
[OpenNoteVisible.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"cornerRadius"];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** solution is below

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, animations: {
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 40
}, completion: { _ in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    })
})
```