# UIView Animation freez

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm using `[UIView animationWithDuration..]` it works great, smooth.. but when I add this effect to UIView, it freezes...

```
 _menuView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
_menuView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-8, 10);
_menuView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
_menuView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

Any ideas? How to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common problem with shadows is that if you do not set the `shadowPath`, the performance will be very poor. Try adding

```
_menuView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_menuView.layer.bounds].CGPath;
```

Assuming, of course, that the view you are animating is indeed rectangular (which is the optimization that I make in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify shadowPath, otherwise layer with recalculate the shadow each frame, which causes great performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's incorrect to animate layer's  properties in the animation block, they are not animatable. Please, read the documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html

Following UIView properties are animatable:

```
  @property frame
  @property bounds
  @property center
  @property transform
  @property alpha
  @property backgroundColor
  @property contentStretch
```

You can use Core Animation and the view’s underlying layer to create the animation. Because view and layer objects are intricately linked together, changes to a view’s layer affect the view itself.

Take a look at this question, it describes how to animate cornerRadius:

[Changing cornerRadius using Core Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511359/changing-cornerradius-using-core-animation)